# Finding Substring With Delimiter SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, delimiter, charindex

Lets say I have a dimension, called "Custom1" that can be 47x29x10 , 01x8x300...etc.

How can I split on the "x" delimiter regardless of the length between the delimiters?

I was successfully able to capture the first and last numbers, but the middle number is giving me trouble.

Here is the code I have already

```
SELECT

TRIM(SUBSTRING(Custom1, 1, CHARINDEX('x',Custom1)-1)) as Length,

SUBSTRING(Custom1, CHARINDEX('x', Custom1) +1, LEN(Custom1) - CHARINDEX('x', Custom1)) as Widths,

REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(Custom1),0,CHARINDEX('x',REVERSE(Custom1)))) as Height

FROM Table
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the DBMS you are using. Are there always going to be 2 x’s in the string or could there be any number?

Comment: there will always be two "x's"

Comment: this is on MSSQL

Comment: The general solution when looking for the offsets is usually to nest the calls. So you'd get the characters between `charindex('x', S)` and `charindex('x', S, charindex('x', S) + 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    PARSENAME(REPLACE(Custom1, 'x', '.'), 3) as Length,
    PARSENAME(REPLACE(Custom1, 'x', '.'), 2) as Width,
    PARSENAME(REPLACE(Custom1, 'x', '.'), 1) as Height
FROM YourTable;
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming no decimals...

This is similar to Samer's response, but here we use a `CROSS APPLY` to create the temp string once

**Example**

```
Select SomeCol 
      ,Pos1 = parsename(tStr,3)
      ,Pos2 = parsename(tStr,2)
      ,Pos3 = parsename(tStr,1)
 From YourTable
 Cross Apply ( values (replace(SomeCol,'x','.'))) B(tStr)
```

Now... If you have decimals, perhaps a little JSON instead?

```
Select A.[SomeCol]
       ,Pos1 = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[0]')
       ,Pos2 = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[1]')
       ,Pos3 = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[2]')
 From  YourTable A
Cross Apply (values ('["'+replace(string_escape([SomeCol],'json'),'x','","')+'"]') ) B(JS)
```

**Both Return**

```
SomeCol     Pos1    Pos2    Pos3
47x29x10    47      29      10
```